# C# Powershell Cmdlet: call another cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I created a set of PowerShell cmdlets in C#.

Now I have a cmdlet that could re-use the code of another one.

In Powershell that would be easy as I could just call the cmdlet with the parameters, however is there a way to call it in C#? The complete logic is implemented in the `BeginProcessing()` /`ProcessRecord()` / `EndProcessing()` implementation and basically returns `void` / use `WriteObject()` so I think it won't be possible (?).

If I am right - what is the a correct way to handle this? Should I extract the essential code out of the `BeginProcessing()` method and put it into a separate method to make it available?

Any feedback is appreciated, 
Joel

Comment: Here's half of an answer. There's some method that you can use to call a cmdlet, but you can only call cmdlets which inherit directly from `Cmdlet`, not cmdlets which inherit from `PSCmdlet`. Even if it is possible to call your cmdlet from C#, factoring out the important stuff into a separate method may be the best solution.

Comment: One of the reasons I asked was because I want to stick with the PSCmdlet "WriteVerbose" / "WriteDebug" features. If I would put the essential code into a separate class I won't be able to call those anymore. However I might find a workaround on that. Thanks for the input!